# Samba share / Window host / Ubuntu Guest

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, samba

[here is samba share lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDksJ.jpg) [Permissions for folder here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3se7C.jpg)I have tried searching for an answer but cannot find one I understand. I have a desktop with Window 10 OS and Ubuntu in a VM. Using virtualbox I am sharing two folders on my Windows host with my Ubuntu vm. I can view/create/delete files and folders on my shared folders using the Ubuntu vm.

I decided to try and learn something about file sharing. I created a samba share in Ubuntu to use with my Windows OS. I can view and create folders from Windows into my Ubuntu samba shares but I cannot delete them from Windows. I can ssh in and delete the folders I create from Windows. I can delete them in Ubuntu but I cannot delete them from Windows file explorer.

I made the samba shares because I want my movie collection available to others in my house without them having to install Plex or something like that. I can watch movies using my VLC app on my laptop this way.
I also wanted to learn how to have a network share etc.

Why can I delete folders on my samba share from a Windows command line but not from file explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Welcome to AskUbuntu.

You're fighting with linux permissions.

By default in samba share you can create files from clients, but you don't have permission to delete them.

When you create a file from a client i.e.(windows) in your samba share, it's created with mask `0644`, but the client is not the owner of the directory, so you can't delete it.

First of all create a specific `user` here I use `sambashare` but you can customize it.

```
sudo adduser --system sambashare
```

Create a mount point

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/MyStuff
```

Change owner of share directory

```
sudo chown -R sambashare:sambashare /mnt/MyStuff
```

Change directory permissions to `755`

```
sudo chmod 755 /mnt/MyStuff
```

Then simple force samba to use user `sambashare`

```
[MyStuff]
path = /mnt/MyStuff
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
read only = no
public = yes
create mask = 2755
directory mask = 2755
force user = sambashare
```

Then restart `samba`

```
sudo systemctl restart smbd
```

Found `uid` and `gid` of created user using

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep sambashare
```

gives `sambashare:x:122:65534::/home/sambashare:/usr/sbin/nologin`

```
cat /etc/group | grep sambashare
```

gives `sambashare:x:122:cube`

According to output `uid` and `gid` are `122`

Edit `/etc/fstab` to add entry for the mount point using correct `uig` and `gid`

```
MyStuff    /mnt/MyStuff  vboxsf  uid=122,gid=122,umask=0022 0 0
```

Note `MyStuff` is the name you provide when you create shared directory under virtualbox.

Now add the module `vboxsf` to `/etc/modules` to force module loading onboot.

In `VirtualBox` application remove the option `automount`.

Then Reboot. Now you should be able to create/delete files in your shared directory from windows.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. When I typed the above I lost access to folder. I commented out public = yes and force user = sambashare and can back into folder and create files again but still cannot delete.I am going to attach what I  think is the permission for folder after the above.

Comment: Looks like when I force user to the username I created it doesn't allow me into folder. If I comment it out I can get back into folder. No dice on deleting folder though

Comment: I made a mistake mask is `2755` not `0755` and I was missing option `read only = no`, I've updated my answer with the correct configuration, I've tried, it's working. Note that old files which were created with `mask 0755`  can't be removed from windows.

Comment: Anytime I force user to the one I created I lose access to folder. When I comment it out I can get back in. Still cannot delete folders. When I force user to my normal username I can access folder but not the one I created about.

Comment: Have you set the permission to the shared folder ?

Comment: I added a snip in my post. I am not allowed to post any pics but it links it.

Comment: Permission for the folder `/media/sf_MyStuff` are incorrect. try `sudo chown -R gee1:gee1 /media/sf_MyStuff` then `sudo chmod 755 /media/sf_MyStuff`, then uncomment `force user` in `smb.conf` and retry

Comment: Can't get back into folder when I force user. I ran above with the username "gee1". Couldn't get in. The main user on Ubuntu is gee. When I force user with that name I can get in folder. When I comment force user out I can also get in. I can create folders with or with out force user "gee". But I cannot get in with "gee1" at all. And I cannot delete except through windows command line and ubuntu gui and terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107529/discussion-between-fractalyse-and-noobcoder).